# How can i get directory file path of particular image folder in Gallery 3d application of samsung S4?

Tags: java, android, android-gallery

In samsung S4 android Gallery application how can i get directory file path of particular image folder like if we click on "Album" from action bar we get a different view likewise "All" , "location"....
Any suggestions would be very helpful.
Thanks in advance.